# Integrate over simplex on Dirichlet-Multinomial distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions

I want to integrate the Dirichlet-Multinomial distribution over all $\alpha$ in a simplex. Specifically, let $T_d := \{ (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_K) : \alpha_k \geq 1, \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_k = C, C \geq K \}$. I want to compute this integral:
$$
\int_{T_d} \prod_{k=1}^K \frac{\Gamma{(x_k + \alpha_k)}}{\Gamma{(\alpha_k)}\Gamma{(x_k + 1)}} \mathrm{d}\alpha
$$
I'm not a mathematician, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

EDIT: I'm starting to get the feeling this integral just evaluates to 1.